# How prepared is "too prepared" for an endgame-like NPC?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, balance, npc, villain

I'm currently running a guild heavy campaign with the two major guilds being the Bandit's Guild and the Adventurer's Guild. The bandits guild runs in territories where noble rank and lord rank bandits being the sort of mafia-head of those areas.

There is a bandit king that doesn't really run anything, he's more of a figure head that other bandits bow their knee to out of respect rather than out of authority. He's kind of a guy that has tools upon tools, but I'm wondering how much is too much.

I kinda want to give him a couple bags of holding each filled with 500lbs worth of Talismans of Ultimate Evil and Talismans of Pure Good as a trick, but I don't know if that's too cruel or not cruel enough. I feel like him turning the bag inside out at someone is kind of a "rocks fall you die", but it is also survivable. I wanna give this guy a Lupin the 3rd "how many tricks does this guy have up his sleeve" type feel, not "man, I'm never chasing after that guy again" vibes.

Would this type of trick be too demoralizing/dirty to use? "You take 4000(or more)d6 radiant/necrotic damage" does sound really fun to say, though. (He has levels in artificer and rogue is how I plan to plot together the seemingly godlike talisman collection.)

What game am I playing?
It's a game designed to run off of the DnD 5E engine.

Are the players aware of this character and their reputation before they meet them?
They will be aware of the character, mostly due to other NPCs claiming to be him. These NPCs (bandit nobles and bandit lords) are going to be designed to be tough to hint that this Bandit King is very strong, and depending on how they approach it they could end up hearing many fantastical stories about him throughout the game.

Are you trying to give this character 'tricks' which can be used to circumvent PC plans (more utility), or outright damage?

Deterrents and distractions are a big part of his kit. Guy is a heist master, so tricks would probably be more in his wheelhouse, but damage also isn't off the table because he is a guy who can steal from gods, and then fall off of the radar.

I also kinda want him to be something that gives PCs ideas for builds in future games. A sort of "wow, and this is something I could potentially build as a player?"

What level are the players, how many are in the party, how long has this campaign been going on?

It's a party of 3, currently. It's designed as a world starting from 1 and going to 20 if the players stick with it (trying to design a world I can pop any players into and have it just go). My most recent party has lasted for 4 sessions so far with another one planned next month. They are about to do get their lead ranking from a level 3 challenge quest and then check out the world a bit. The bandits guild has shown interest in a couple of the players. One is an experiment in giving creatures magical powers which did have side effects, and another is from a merchants guild family and blackmailed a bandit lord who thought it was cute and passed a few PP her way. I figure if they run into him at level 3, he can just misty-step away, no problem. I have plenty of experience at running low level campaigns, I just don't know how much is too much at high levels. Watching player struggle to breath at level 3 kinda makes me wary of how I should design endgame beings. It also doesn't help that their comp isn't the greatest, but it is interesting and I want to tell a good story. A cleric that doesn't know they're a cleric and is prone to panic attacks, a changeling bard that killed their sister and took her place, and a half-orc sorcerer that has some strange necrosis going on has a lot of use-able plot points.

Am I thinking too far ahead, and shouldn't worry about something that is this late game? There's still like 5 bandit lords, and 20 bandit nobles to introduce, and then the list of generic bandits that run under their organization, and one of those bandit lords is a beholder that made a deal with Asmodeus to perma-illusion a human over the top of him to everyone except himself, which is more like mid-game content. Not sure how much more detail I should add, but I'll add as much as I can if it helps kinda figure out if a talisman bomb is too much, or if I need to dial things down a bit. There's a chance this character never makes an appearance and is lost to the shadows on a spreadsheet at the bottom of an ssd, and there's a chance that players decide they want to try the world on level 20 in a parallel universe or something.

How many talismans of ultimate evil exist in your world? Even if this is the most perfect plan and amazingly balanced, as a player I would be really confused that they were not only not unique, but that one person could obtain loads of them. Its not exactly believable.

The idea is that he discovered and heisted what few talismans existed in the world, did a bit of reverse engineering through "artificer yada yada yada", figured out what he'd need to make them, and made a bunch during a month long vacation to the outer realms. I could probably tone it down to less totems, because 1000lbs worth of totems seems like a lot of hours to put in, but toning it down seems like a good point. This is an entity that basically has the ability to run the world if they wanted to, but prefers a quiet peaceful life of being left alone, which is why he created the adventures guild as a way to stay a step ahead of the other high-ranking bandits. Right now he is my "last guy", but as we approach the end, he might just become the guy holding back the flood gates, and I'd assume they'd be massive flood gates at level 20

On reading the update, is this question about designing the toolkit of this NPC, or about the viability of the described talisman-bomb? This feels like it's trying to pull double-duty.

After all the questions started hitting I kinda got lost on the original idea for the question. I'll probably let this thread die because the questions asked gave me even more things to think about fleshing this guy out. There are a lot of directions I can go with this guy, and the questions asked about my question kinda helped me figure out some important things I might have missed.

Thanks for the feedback, it gave me some direction on this, sorry about not really having a resolvable question, or having one and losing it in train of thought. I've got a lot going on in this world, and we're getting closer and closer to the end of prepared content. Again, sorry for losing my original question, but thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Are the players aware of this character and their reputation before they meet them?

Comment: Not being familiar with Lupin 3rd, are you trying to give this character 'tricks' which can be used to circumvent PC plans (more utility), or outright *damage*?

Comment: What level are the players, how many are in the party, how long has this campaign been going on?

Comment: On reading the update, is this question about designing the toolkit of this NPC, or about the viability of the described talisman-bomb? This feels like it's trying to pull double-duty.

Comment: How many talismans of ultimate evil exist in your world? Even if this is the most perfect plan and amazingly balanced, as a player I would be really confused that they were not only not unique, but that one person could obtain loads of them. Its not exactly believable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Make your worldbuilding believable

You've told us that this person has *thousands* of legendary items.  That's enough wealth to buy the kingdom.  That's enough wealth to buy *all* the kingdoms!

If he can make legendary items that cheaply, then why is he a bandit, instead of the greatest artificer ever known?

Is the rest of his gear similarly legendary?  Is he wearing +3 armor and a +3 shield, et cetera, et cetera?

The books that give +2 stat are only "very rare".  Has he manufactured ten of each book and maxed out all his stats?  Has he done the same for all his friends?

I don't think there's a believable way to give this guy *that* much wealth and still have him be a bandit king.

### The problem is the wealth is being used inefficiently

It's like if you did a fight against the US President, and he had an attack called the Billion Dollar Bill Chaingun, which was a gun that shot rolled-up billion-dollar bills at people.

Players would say: "okay, we get it, this guy is absurdly insanely rich.  But is this really the best use he could think of for that money?"

## Your proposed trick requires house rules to work

You've told us that the bandit would "turn the bag inside out at someone", but there are no rules for how many talismans would touch the target if this happened.  The rules just say:

> If the bag is turned inside out, its contents spill forth, unharmed...

and it's not clear that the contents would touch anyone, and it's also not clear that more of them would touch the player character than the person who's actually holding the bag.

You can houserule this to work, of course.  But if you're willing to use DM power to produce house rules for this, it seems like you could houserule something that would be simpler and more believable, and it would make for a better game.

Comment: Yeah, going for believable on a world-class+ entity is tricky. I may put floodgates behind him so that there's something to do after level 20. I need to work on the why and how. I think making it believable is the answer I was looking for. For clarification, is the hangup mostly on the title "Bandit King"? The Bandit's Guild is at least a continent+ level organization that secretly runs the merchants guild. I think this answer is the answer, though. Deck out everyone he cares about, and make his enemies powerful enough to warrant needing so much power.

Comment: If they have the resources for thousands of legendary items, they have enough resources to defeat almost any enemy and don't need cheap tricks.

Comment: -1.  If you pour a bag of lollypops over someone's head, they are going to be touched by at least some of the lollypops.  D&D 5E is not a physics simulator, but basic common sense is going to be applied by the vast majority of tables.  At the very least, the DM would ask for some kind of save to 'dodge' all of the lollypops.

Answer (score 10):

### Lupin's tricks are cool because they are not innately powerful, they are used cleverly.

Effectively, a guy who is infinitely powerful is cool only briefly.  He blows up a mountain with his talismans or whatever and that's cool for about the length of time it takes for people to imagine an explosion, and the effect this guy could have on the rest of the setting.   Then it starts being cool only in the sense that you have done narrative framing to extrapolate that power onto other things, such that it retains enough verisimilitude to be believable and real.  Without which, it stops being cool very very fast.

Going 'he is all powerful' is not meaningfully something the party can interact with.  It's like saying 'a god comes to fight you', to a bunch of level 1 PCs.  An enemy that is sneaky is fun because if you out-thought him you could beat him.  Even if the DM is cheating to make that enemy sneaky only in retrospect in some cases (like 'you chase after him... roll Dexterity vs the pit trap that just opened beneath you', when there was no pit trap there in your notes.. you just added it because it made sense for the sneaky rogue to have set up a trap and you just weren't clever enough to pre-plan it).  That's a challenge, an adventure, believable, and interesting.

That's how that kind of character is typically used.  'Lol you die' is not particularly fun, interesting, a challenge, or even believable (why is this guy a 'bandit king' if he has the power of a minor deity).

Comment: +1 for the 'Lol you die' being not a fun thing for the players

Comment: I know you're probably referencing an Arsene Lupin, but which specific Arsene Lupin did you have in mind? There's at least three, and knowing which one you meant would help frame your answer.

Comment: @GMJoe any.  to my knowledge all iterations of arsene lupin are gentleman thieves and masters of disguise that use trickery and guile to achieve their aims.  I mostly mention him because the question does, in the context of an incorrect usage (overwhelming power)

Comment: Bandit king is more akin to One Piece's "Pirate King", but I do want to give him the Vash dress-up with a "please don't chase me" set of toys. He's not actually a badguy, he just has a VERY large bounty on his head from Gods, Demi-Gods, Kings, His own organization (they'll never admit that, though), and maybe a few outside of known existence. He does have several other tricks up his sleeve to ramp up to before going full deterrent. I don't want a Lupin clone, per se. He's also kinda like an optional super-boss than something they'll interact with normally.

Answer (score 1):

## Artificers can't make infinite or massive numbers of magical items of legendary quality.

Artificers can't make legendary items much better than other people, and legendary items cost 500k coins to make generally. They are limited to a small number of infusions that isn't the thousands you suggest.

As such, you wouldn't be teasing your players with what they could do, you'd be teasing them with impossible acts that are beyond anything but an interdimensional king who rules worlds to fuel their incredible wealth could do.

It also risks massively unbalancing your campaign, in that they have billions of gp of wealth.

## Do an artificer bag of holding bomb instead.

Make a bag of holding and a Quiver of Ehlonna.

> Each of the quiver's three compartments connects to an extradimensional space that allows the quiver to hold numerous items while never weighing more than 2 pounds. The shortest compartment can hold up to sixty arrows, bolts, or similar objects. The midsize compartment holds up to eighteen javelins or similar objects. The longest compartment holds up to six long objects, such as bows, quarterstaffs, or spears.
> You can draw any item the quiver contains as if doing so from a regular quiver or scabbard.

> Placing a bag of holding inside an extradimensional space created by a Handy Haversack, Portable Hole, or similar item instantly destroys both items and opens a gate to the Astral Plane. The gate originates where the one item was placed inside the other. Any creature within 10 feet of the gate is sucked through it to a random Location on the Astral Plane. The gate then closes. The gate is one-way only and can't be reopened.

This is an easy and localized bomb to make, assuming you rule that a quiver has an extradimensional space similar to a Handy Haversack, and just requires you to be level 10 as an artificer. It's a perfectly reasonable way to mess with players, and doesn't end the campaign if they get hit by it as they can just escape the astral plane.

Comment: To give some feedback on my downvote, the idea you suggest in the second section is something I would recommend to nobody.

Comment: Is there any reason? Making a bag of holding bomb is rules legal, and even for non artificers not something that would break the bank for a single encounter with players.

Comment: Would this trick still be effective at level 20+?

Comment: At level 20 they could escape much more easily with level appropriate spells, but it would definitely distract the players while the guy escaped.